# Extracting slopes from TIFF file

Tags: gis, geopandas, tiff, rasterio

I have a TIF file from Portugal with the slopes of the terrain. I would like to select areas with a certain slope, for example only areas with slope less than 20%, using python

Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried several codes with rasterio and geopandas but I do not find the way. My idea is to plot a shapefile of Portugal showing only certain areas

Comment: You may have greater success if you share your TIFF and your latest/greatest code as [mcve].